# Compartilhar informações entre páginas php

Tags: php, html, jquery-datatables

Estou desenvolvendo um conteúdo WEB e me deparei com um empecilho.
Tenho uma página de Listagem de itens (Utilizando JqDataTable).

[image: Listagem de itens]

Acontece que nessa listagem há dois links, um para edição do item referente a linha, e outro para a exclusão.

Ao clicar nos ícones de alterar ou excluir, o usuário deve ser redirecionado para a respectiva página, e essa página deve receber o código do item que o usuário deseja alterar ou excluir.

Não sei o que colocar nos "onclick" para que isso seja feito.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: Código Fonte]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá para você usar `location.href` com **PHP - GET and POST methods**.

```
onClick="location.href='delete.php?itemId=1'"
```

Ai na sua página que **delete.php** você usa `$_GET` para recuperar

```
$itemId= $_GET['itemId'];
```

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de colocar uma caixa de confirmação perguntando e o usuario deseja mesmo deletar aquele item?

Comment: Sim @D_Alves . Dá para fazer isso de diversas formas. Uma delas é criar uma função em javascript;